# Is it possible to check if already value then not set that field?

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore

I setData after login successfully. All values are null except phone number. after that user can edit profile and set displayName and email and other fields. **but all fields are again null when the user logs out and log in.**

Is it possible to check if already value then not set that field?

```
  Future<void> addUser(UserModel model){
    return _db.collection('users').document(model.uid).setData({
      'displayName':model.displayName,
      'email':model.email,
      'phone':model.phone,
      'photoUrl':model.photoUrl,
      'title':model.title,
      'vendorCircle':model.vendorCircle,
      'type':model.type,
    },merge: true);
  }
```

Comment: I don't understand what the problem is.  Are you saying that the fields seem to change values automatically?  Are you making another call to setData somewhere?  Data will never change if some code isn't explicitly updating it.

Comment: I think you're asking if a user already exists that you don't want `addUser` to be called?

Comment: No, Sorry for my bad English. All fields are null except phone number for first time user. okay?.. after that this user can edit profile. it's mean add values to other fields. and this user can log out and login. this time, set all fields are null except phone number.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Solution**

```
  Future<void> addUser(UserModel model) {
    if (model.photoUrl != '' &&
        model.email != '' &&
        model.displayName != '' &&
        model.title != '' &&
        model.vendorCircle != '') {
      return _db.collection('users').document(model.uid).setData({
        'displayName': model.displayName,
        'email': model.email,
        'phone': model.phone,
        'photoUrl': model.photoUrl,
        'title': model.title,
        'vendorCircle': model.vendorCircle,
        'type': model.type,
      }, merge: true);
    } else if (model.email != '' &&
        model.displayName != '' &&
        model.vendorCircle != ''){
      return _db.collection('users').document(model.uid).setData({
        'displayName': model.displayName,
        'email': model.email,
        'phone': model.phone,
        'vendorCircle': model.vendorCircle,
          'type':model.type
      }, merge: true);
    }else{
      return _db.collection('users').document(model.uid).setData({
        'phone': model.phone,
        'type':model.type
      }, merge: true);
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Setting a `null` value on a field is precisely the operation you're asking for: it sets `null` on that field. There is no configuration option on Firestore to change that behavior.

What you can do is build the model conditionally on the Flutter/Dart side. Something like:

```
var data = {
  'displayName':model.displayName,
  'email':model.email,
  'phone':model.phone,
  'photoUrl':model.photoUrl,
  'title':model.title,
  'vendorCircle':model.vendorCircle,
  'type':model.type,
};
data.removeWhere((k,v) => v == null);

_db.collection('users').document(model.uid).setData(data, merge: true);
```

Inspired by this [comment on github](https://github.com/dart-lang/language/issues/47#issuecomment-433227123) and the documentation of the [`removeWhere` method](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/dart-core/Map/removeWhere.html).

Comment: ```Error: This expression has type 'void' and can't be used.
      }.removeWhere((k,v) => v == null), merge: true);```

Comment: Right, sorry about that. The `removeWhere` method modified the existing map, and doesn't return one (see also the linked docs). I updated the answer to extract the map before passing it to the database.

Comment: The code is okay. but samething happening.. Sorry for my bad English. all fields are null except phone number when login first time. okay?.. after that this user can edit profile. it's mean add values to db(displayName,email...) afterthat user can log out and login. this time, set all fields are null except phone number again.

Comment: I edit my question and added solution.. can you check is it best practice or is there any best way to do?

Comment: Great to hear that you've found a solution. However, please don't edit it into your question. Instead post it in an answer, so that folks can judge question and answer separately.

Comment: You might want to check my answer again. There was one remaining typo (somehow I miscopied from the Dartpad where I tested this), and it'd be a lot less code than your approach.

Comment: I tried again.. but no wrking..thanks your support.